# Nested RecyclerView scrolling performance

Tags: android, performance, xamarin, android-recyclerview, mvvmcross

Is there a way to force nested RecyclerView to actually recycling? I have a list of items with long lists in it. During the scrolling nested `RecyclerView` is actually loading and layouting all the items before showing only visible at a screen now.

Both recylers are vertical and nested one has `wrap_content` for `layout_height`.

Can this be achieved by custom layout manager? Maybe there is an existing solution for rendering long list of lists? Maybe [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) does some optimizations and can be used in order to achieve recycling?

Here is a [small sample app](https://1drv.ms/u/s!As2k79wAgoRE0GJtaeClI2tGZusH). If you scroll up and down you will see ui is lagging a lot.

Comment: So, your main list is vertical, and your item lists are horizontal?

Comment: Try with _recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool.setMaxRecycledViews(50);_. For more info check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool.html#setMaxRecycledViews(int,%20int))

Comment: How did you tell that your Recycler inst performing the recycling? cuz taking time to load has so many factor to consider.

Comment: Because when I scroll up and down there is noticeable lag before item that was visible just now is rendered and added to a view again

Comment: @Sly Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're not supposed to be doing this. Use an expandable list pattern instead both for better performance and to avoid confusing user experience.

Comment: and in order to get smooth scrolling child items will need to be collapsed by default?

Comment: If you will use the RecyclerView properly (as in, let it actually recycle the items), this wouldn't really matter.